# Using parts of a string to search and find a cell reference

Tags: google-sheets

I've been toying with a few ways to do what I want to do, so I'll start with an example of my goal:

[image]

So, in the linked sheet, I have a table with colors and animals, and then a list of entries, each with a color and animal together. My goal is this: Take the string from one of the cells in `column E`, i.e. `E2: Red Cat`, and use that information to find the associated cell, and return either the cell reference `B2`, or the data contained where they intersect, in this case `TRUE`.

Answer (score 1):

I opted for the cell content rather than the cell addresses. Please try:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,MATCH(INDEX(split(E2," "),1),A:A,0)-1,MATCH(INDEX(split(E2," "),2),$1:$1,0)-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you alter a little bit code given by @pnuts then you will get cell reference:

```
=ADDRESS(MATCH(INDEX(SPLIT(E2," "),1),A:A,0),MATCH(INDEX(SPLIT(E2," "),1,2),$1:1,0),4)
```

The last paramether could be 1-4 and the results:

1. $B$2
2. B$2
3. $B2
4. B2

also you are able to add sheet name to reference, then it would be:

```
=ADDRESS(MATCH(INDEX(SPLIT(E2," "),1),A:A,0),MATCH(INDEX(SPLIT(E2," "),1,2),$1:1,0),4,,"SheetName")
```

and the result -> SheetName!B2

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a good way to automate your task is to use array formulas:

[image]

The formula is F1 to split values:

`=FILTER(SPLIT(E2:E," "),E2:E<>"")`

The formula in H2 to get addresses:

`=FILTER(ADDRESS(MATCH(F2:F,A:A,),MATCH(G2:G,1:1,),4),E2:E<>"")`

or put this in H2 to get values:

`=FILTER(VLOOKUP(F2:F,A:C,MATCH(G2:G,1:1,),0),E2:E<>"")`

[image]